# good practice or bad practice updating instance variable from inner class

Tags: java

Say I have a private (inner) class `Child` inside another class `Parent`:

```
public class Parent {
   private boolean isBusy;
   private Child child = new Child();

   public void doSomething() {
      child.playToy();
   }

   private class Child {

     protected void playToy() {
          isBusy = true;
     }
   }
}
```

As you see above, `Parent` class has a boolean instance variable `isBusy` , the private inner class `Child` has a function `playToy()` which updates that boolean. Is it a **bad practice** to update a instance variable defined in upper class from inner class? If it is bad practice, what are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Child`  is a private class and can only be instantiated by `Parent` I don't see any drawbacks in doing it.

Of course, if you handle multiple instances of `Child` in your `Parent` implementation than you'll need to take care of concurrency, but that dependes on what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a private class and it will be only instantiated in the outer class I don't see any drawbacks. This concept is actually quite common for example with a inner class extending a listener which manipulates the outer fields.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no problem. You can change variable's value as per your requirement.